# Networkx Edge_Color inconstancies

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

Hi I'm trying to use networkx in order to graph data from a neuronal network.
Neurons connexions can either be excitatory or inhibitory. I made a DataFrame with columns from/to/value. Value is a categorical variable coding for excitatory or inhibitory.
However I have some inconsistencies. Here I'm showing Neuron n°245 if I'm plotting the whole data vs If I only plot for

```py
df = df[(df['from'] == 245) | (df['to'] == 245)]
```

With Full Dataset

[image]

With only n°245

[image]

As you can see some edge doesn't have the same colour ... Such as the N245-N234

Here is the code that I'm using :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'from':pre_syn,'to':post_syn,'value':type_syn})
df['value']=pd.Categorical(df['value'])
df = df[(df['from'] == 245) | (df['to'] == 245)]

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph() )
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3', with_labels=True, node_size=500, edge_color=df['value'].cat.codes,
        width=1.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Set1)
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't think there are any inconsistencies. You're only keeping the edges in which one of the nodes is 245. Whereas in the first plot, you also see other connections, but these aren't directly linked with 245, for instance the edge `(233,237)`. And from what I can see, your code seems completely fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please look closely at the connection between N245 and N234. In the first graph both connexion are red, in the second one is red, the other is grey. I look into the data and the second graph is the correct one

Comment: Python 3.7 with Anaconda

Comment: Try specifying an `edgelist` when drawing as `G.edges`. And set the edge color as an attribute of the edges, then use that attribute to set the color in `nx.draw`

Comment: As a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599686/9698684

Comment: Hi Yatu, thank you very much for the help. You solve my problem. I used ```nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'color')``` and it's working perfectly. Do you know what was the problem when directly using the dataframe ?
I also tried using ```G.add_edge()``` and ```nx.draw(edge_color = df['value'].values)``` but I got the same problem ...

Do you now if there is an easy way to contact the DevTeam of NetworkX in order to tell them ? Should I write in their github ?

Comment: Well it seems that the edge order in the dataframe is not necessarily the same as that if the graphs edge list. So guessing that was it